# Confusion over definition of continuity and limit of a function

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $x$ be a point in domain of a function $f$. In high school calculus, we used to say that $lim_{t -> x}f(t)$ exists if both the left and right limit exists and both are equal, but they need not be equal to $f(x)$. But, in Rudin's real analysis book, it is mentioned that $lim_{t -> x}f(t)$ exists iff $f$ is continuous at $x$. Is this observation correct or am I wrong ?

Comment: No. For continuity, the limit must exist, and the function value at that point should equal the limit.

Comment: In other words, both your HS recollection and interpretation of Rudin are wrong.

Comment: I doubt that you can find that claim in Rudin's book.

Comment: @egreg Why? It's the (well, one of the two) natural definition of the limit of a function when the point is in the domain.

Comment: From your high school definition, notice that you aren't requiring continuity of $f(x)$. If $f(x)$ is continuous, then the limit as you have written exists and equals $f(x)$. If $f(x)$ is not continuous, then there is no reason to suspect that the limit exists, much less equal $f(x)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer The function $f(x)=0$ for $x\ne0$, $f(0)=1$ has the property that $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$ exists, but surely it is *not* continuous at $0$.

Comment: @egreg No, its limit at $0$ doesn't exist. Not with the definition Rudin uses (and I learned).

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm not expert of the baby Rudin; but defining limits only for continuous functions seems quite useless.

Comment: @egreg The concept is useful mostly when the point where the limit is taken/sought does not belong to the domain of $f$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I *know* that! The definition you report in your answer has the implicit assumption that $t$ belongs to the domain of $f$, which in my opinion should be explicit.

Comment: @all: sorry, I was wrong.

Comment: @user96000 : Rudin would not write what you say he wrote because it's wrong (unless there is some context that you left out of your question).  The definition you learned in high school calculus is correct and Rudin uses it.  I have never heard of _anyone_ using a different one.  $f(x)$ can be anything and does not even need to exist.

Comment: @user96000 : if you were wrong (such as misquoting Rudin), you should fix your question.  By the way, "\lim" gives you a nice-looking lim, and "\to" gives you an arrow.

Answer (score 1):

Different people use different definitions.

One definition is that $L = \lim\limits_{t\to x} f(t)$ exists iff for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$, such that

$$\bigl(\forall t \in \operatorname{dom} f\bigr)\bigl(\lvert t-x\rvert < \delta \Rightarrow \lvert f(t) - L\rvert < \varepsilon\bigr).$$

That is easily seen to be equivalent to the continuity of $f$ at $x$.

The high-school definition (and as [Christian Blatter](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1303/christian-blatter) pointed out, that is also the one Rudin uses) excludes the point $x$ from the consideration. The condition then reads

$$\bigl(\forall t \in \operatorname{dom} f\bigr)\bigl(0 < \lvert t-x\rvert < \delta \Rightarrow \lvert f(t) - L\rvert < \varepsilon\bigr).$$

That construction is also useful.

The concept of the limit of $f$ at $x$ is most important and useful when the point $x$ is not in the domain of $f$, but an accumulation point of it. Then the existence of the limit is equivalent to the existence of an extension of $f$ that is continuous in $x$.

Comment: This is simply not true. Look at section 4.1 of baby Rudin. Verbatim he says: "Moreover, even if $p\in E$, we may very well have $f(p)\ne\lim_{x\to p}f(x)$.

Comment: Ah, okay, I don't have the Principles, I believed the OP's recollection.